# SSL on a DotNetNuke portal

Tags: asp.net, ssl, dotnetnuke

I have a question.

I have never worked with a DotNetNuke setup with SSL before.  Our server has SSL set up correctly on the server via our hosting company.

My question is, if I enable SSL on one of my DNN portals, are there any gotchas or settings I need to be aware of, assuming the server is set up correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your whole site isn't going to be secured by SSL, keep in mind that the Admin and Host areas will automatically redirect to SSL secured versions of those pages.  In this scenario, depending on your web host, I've encountered infinite redirect issues which made it so that I could not access the admin and host areas.  This ultimately was due to how the web host was offloading their SSL traffic.

Other than that, as long as you've got the certificate installed correctly, and SSL enabled in DNN, I don't foresee any other problems.

Comment: thanks for the answer, I've implemented SSL on my DNN site and have had no problems.